# C++ program test case acceptance

Tags: c++

I've attempted to solve a coding contest out of curiosity. Out there, there's one of the problems which couldn't pass all the test cases for my solution. Could there be any improvement in my solution that you would suggest that might help? TIA. The problem along with my solution is stated down below.
The Constraints:

```
1 ≤ M,N ≤ 10^7,
1 ≤ a[i],b[i] ≤ 10^7
```

The Output:

> Print a single int that the maximum cool value that he
> can obtain after buying two items with the given
> amount of money

And my solution is:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    long long N, M, C, count;

    cin>>N>>M>>C;

    long long a[N], b[M];

    for(long long i=0; i<N; i++){
        cin>>a[i];
    }

    for(long long i=0; i<M; i++){
        cin>>b[i];
    }

    sort(a, a+N);
    sort(b, b+M);


    if(a[N-1] + b[M-1] <= C){
        count = (N-1) + (M-1);
        cout<<count<<endl;
    }
    else{
        cout<<"Not even closer"<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

Can anyone suggest what I could improve here to pass all the test?
```

Comment: Have you tried devising test cases to test the very limits of specified input, including weird stuff to stress your program and its assumptions?  That's what problem designers do, and you're falling right into their trap.  Sample input is almost _always_ simplified in order to hide common traps for the unaware.  This tests your ability to read a specification and deliver on it, which includes the skill of figuring out how to verify correctness of your own code without supplied examples.

Comment: Are you learning programming and C++ from such competition sites? Or are you just using their common bad habits for when you write programs for such sites? There are many things in the shown code that is bad or outright invalid C++.

Comment: Even for competition assignments, please don't use the bad habits taught on such sites. Habits, good and bad, tend to stick. So better use good habits everywhere and have them stick.

Comment: Could you explain what your `build` function is exactly doing?

Comment: I would have expected a simple sorting of A and B, and then maximize `i+j` such that `A[i]+B[j] <= C`

Comment: If I am not wrong, after sorting, the price `A[i]` has a coolness equal to `i`.

Comment: The post is not understandable anymore after the edit you made

Answer (score 1):

After sorting, the price `a[i]` has a coolness equal to `i`.

Therefore, a solution consists in sorting `a` and `b`, and then maximize `i+j` such that `a[i]+a[j] <= C`

This last optimisation is performed by a simple `for` loop, with two indices, one for `a` and one for `b`

Complexity is dominated by sorting: O(NlogN + MlogM)

Note: the code currently posted in the question was edited after some comments, and do not correspond to the original code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(NULL);

    int N, M, C;
    std::cin >> N >> M >> C;
    std::vector<int> a(N), b(M);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
        std::cin >> a[i];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < M; i++){
        std::cin >> b[i];
    }

    sort(a.begin(), a.end());
    sort(b.begin(), b.end());

    if(a[0] + b[0] > C) {
        std::cout <<"E kemon aynabaji!!!" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    
    int max_cool = 0;
    int iB = M-1;
    for (int iA = 0; iA < N; ++iA) {
        while (iB >= 0 && (a[iA] + b[iB] > C)) {
            iB--;
        }
        if (iB < 0) break;
        int cool = iA + iB;
        if (cool > max_cool) max_cool = cool;
    }

    std::cout << max_cool << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```